# Unserialize not working in php 5.5.26

Tags: php, arrays

I had a function that took the serialized data, turned into array, added to the array to then push it back to the MySQL DB perfect....in php 7. When I uploaded for a client they have php 5.5.26 and now its not working. It looks like the unserialized variable still has a string, not array so it doesnt add to it.

What was working in php 7

```
       $dashboard = DB::queryFirstField("SELECT dashboard_array FROM compel_dashboard 
                                      WHERE user_id = %i", $user_id);

        $array = unserialize($dashboard);
        array_push($array, $dashboard_item);


        $query  = DB::update('compel_dashboard', array(
                        'dashboard_array' => serialize($array)
                      ), "user_id=%s", $user_id);
```

Whats going on:

`$dashboard` contains `string(27) "s:19:"dashboard-recommend";"`

`$array` contains `string(19) "dashboard-recommend"`

So obviously I cant `push_array` to a string. Whats going on? Why would this work with PHP 7?

Comment: What error(s) do you receive after executing this script?

Comment: Echo out what you're getting in PHP7. Maybe when you try pushing to `$array`, PHP7 is casting it as an array.

Comment: @C0dekid I am not getting any errors from the script. Its just passing a stripped down string back as opposed to an array